# How to print a PDF file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code

```
  Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String filename) async {
    http.Client _client = new http.Client();
    var req = await _client.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var bytes = req.bodyBytes;
    // String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    String dir = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file;
  }

  /// Prints a sample pdf printer
  void printPdfFile() async {
    var file = await _downloadFile(
        "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", "test.pdf");
    await FlutterPdfPrinter.printFile(file.path);
  }
```

I am implementing print PDF files which is saved in my device. When trying to print the document I am getting error like "A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_pdf_printer'."

I am using flutter_pdf_printer dependency to print PDF files.

Comment: Do you know any solution which support null safety because 'flutter_pdf_printer dependency' this isn't supported now due to null safety. So please help me if you know the solution. I want to print pdf file which i am getting in api response as a firebase url. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this dependency didn't helped me.i have skipped this implementation

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string url to URI, please make sure you are adding http

http: ^0.13.4

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

```
     Uri uri = Uri.parse('Your link here');
                            http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
                            var pdfData = response.bodyBytes;
                            await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat 
                            format) async => pdfData);
```